# How to stop sudo PAM messages in auth.log for a specific user on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sudo, pam, rsyslog

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to stop `/var/auth.log` being flooded by a script that checks if some hosts are alive on the network periodically. The script internally uses `sudo` with `nmap`.

I have this in my `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file:

```
#%PAM-1.0

session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0 ruser = deployer
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive

session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0 ruser = deployer
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0
```

However, I am still seeing this in /var/log/auth.log:

```
Dec  1 10:27:43 TimeBox sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec  1 10:27:44 TimeBox sudo: deployer : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/data/deployer/timeagent ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nmap -sn -PR -n -v0 -oX /tmp/nmap.xml20161201-5387-rn90pj 192.168.88.16
Dec  1 10:27:44 TimeBox sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec  1 10:27:44 TimeBox sudo: deployer : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/data/deployer/timeagent ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nmap -sn -PR -n -v0 -oX /tmp/nmap.xml20161201-5387-dni0n5 192.168.88.20
Dec  1 10:27:44 TimeBox sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec  1 10:27:44 TimeBox sudo: deployer : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/data/deployer/timeagent ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nmap -sn -PR -n -v0 -oX /tmp/nmap.xml20161201-5387-1vk93k7 192.168.88.19
Dec  1 10:27:44 TimeBox sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec  1 10:27:44 TimeBox sudo: deployer : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/data/deployer/timeagent ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nmap -sn -PR -n -v0 -oX /tmp/nmap.xml20161201-5387-j4hcxl 192.168.88.21
Dec  1 10:27:44 TimeBox sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec  1 10:27:44 TimeBox sudo: deployer : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/data/deployer/timeagent ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nmap -sn -PR -n -v0 -oX /tmp/nmap.xml20161201-5387-6krabn 192.168.88.13
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are checking too many time (per second) if the site is alive. I would also change the logic of checking (why need to log for checking?). Note the flood is not only on auth.log, but also on other logs.

Comment: The flood is just on auth.log and I am not checking too many times, they are all different IPs.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the issue was with @include common-session-noninteractive - this works for me in /etc/pam.d/sudo:

```
  #%PAM-1.0

  session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0 ruser = deployer
  session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
  session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0

  @include common-auth
  @include common-account
  # @include common-session-noninteractive
```

And I also created /etc/rsyslog.d/35-pam_unix.conf to prevent the logging of the actual sudo line:

```
if $syslogtag contains 'sudo' and $msg contains '/data/deployer/timeagent' then ~
```

Answer (score 0):

You 3 choices:

- run nmap as root
- do a filter regex at syslog level
- modify source

The 1st one is the recommended way.

Comment: 1) All scripts run as the deployer user 2) I can do, but there is a way to handle this in /etc/pam.d/cron, I just didn't get the syntax right 3) There is be a way to handle this in /etc/pam.d/cron without modifying the source